# Using arrays inside a list in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

We are supposed to do is put log entries (title and entry) in a sort of journal. That means having a list with each containing an array with room for two strings.

Now. We've worked with arrays and lists but never together.

Considering this is a school assignment I'm only asking for guidance to point me in the right direction.

So creating a list that on each entry contains space for an array of size 2. How should I think about this concept baring in mind I've only used them separately before?

Comment: I am not sure what you are confused about. It is a list where each element is an an array with enough size to hold two strings. Where is the confusion?

Comment: `List<string[]>` would be perfectly valid, although a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` or a  `List<LogEntry>` where `LogEntry` is a _class_ with two string _properties_ would be more idiomatic.  Note that there's not a _declarative_ way to set the size of the underlying array.

Comment: Also, if you'd like you can just use a list nested in a list like `List<List<string>>`, though Stanley's answer is better in terms of design. If you *need* to use arrays and lists, his `List<string[]>` solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `List<string[]>` is a perfectly valid data structure, although a `List<Tuple<string, string>>` or a  `List<LogEntry>` where `LogEntry` is a *class* with two string *properties* would be more idiomatic.

Note that there's not a *declarative* way to set the size of the underlying array (meaning that `List<string[2]>` is not a valid type.

Comment: This way seems to fit this particular assignment the best. I've worked with classes before and since I could put methods inside this class as well it worked well for when I for instance want to print all the content of an entry as well as when need to search the.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have to have a log title and entry, have you considered wrapping those in a separate class rather than using an array of two strings?

I mean doing something like this:

```
public class LogItem
{
    public string Item;
    public string Entry;
}
```

Then instead of having a list of arrays, you would just use a list of `LogItem`:

```
var myList = new List<LogItem>();

var myNewLogEntry = new LogItem {Title = "Entry title", Entry = "Entry message"};

myList.Add(myNewLogEntry);
```

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't figure out a problem for 2 days until I saw this! Awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You can easily make list of arrays:

```
var myList = new List<string[]>();

myList.Add(new [] { "Fruit", "Orange" });
myList.Add(new [] { "Car", "Toyota" });

Console.WriteLine(myList[0][1]); // Prints "Orange"
Console.WriteLine(myList[1][0]); // Prints "Car"
```

Note, that array length for the particular item may differ. There's no way to limit it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this goes against the assignment, but I would suggest thinking a bit object oriented about this, consider what you're asking for:

> We are supposed to do is put **log entries (title and entry) in a sort of journal**.

In my head this translates to two classes:

First a class "Log" with two string properties, "Title" and "Entry"
Second a class "Journal" with a List<Log> property named Entries.

Code example:

```
public class Journal
{
    ...
    public List<Log> Entries { get; set; }
}

public class Log
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Entry { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create it like that. Is that what you were looking for?

```
List<string[]> myList = new List<string[]>();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely valid data structure.

```
List<string[]> logList = new List<string[]>(); 
logList.Add(new string[] {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"});
```

Besides this, I am not sure what you are looking for.